# Relation between volume and determinant.

Tags: geometry, volume

I'm investigating the derivation of the formula for the volume of an $n$-dimensional ellipsoid. I found this in literature: If $S_n$ is an $n$-sphere and we transform it to an ellipsoid using the positive definite matrix $M$, then the volume of the ellipsoid $E_n$ is

$$
V(E_n) = det (M) V(S_n).
$$

Can someone explain to me the background of this? By what means can we just take the determinant "out"?

Comment: I think this needs to be $$
V(E_n) = |\det (M)| V(S_n).
$$

Comment: @N8tron I forgot to mention that M is positive definite.

Comment: I think $M$ is just the Jacobian under some disguise https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitively it is true. Using the change of variables theorem,

$$\det (M) \cdot V(D_n) = \int_{D_n} \det (M) \, dx_1\cdots dx_n = \int_{M(D_n)} dM(x_1)\cdots dM(x_n) = V(E_n)$$

Note that the Jacobian of the transformation $M$ is $M$ itself.